# Updating Values in R

Tags: r, matrix, vector

Suppose I have the following code:

```
 x <- vector(mode="numeric", length=10)
 for(i in 1:10)
    {
       x[i] <- runif(1,0,10)
    }
```

So  `x`  has 10 values. In each of the next steps, I want to add 10 new values to  `x` . So in step 2,  `x`  would have 20 values, in step 3 it would have 30 values etc. How would I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Append value to empty vector in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22235809/append-value-to-empty-vector-in-r)

Comment: Any particular reason for using a loop? `runif` is vectorized and can give you all these values at once.

Answer (score 2):

one way you can do it:

```
x <- vector(mode="numeric")
for(i in 1:10)
{
  x<-c(x, runif(10,0,10))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One possibility is to use a matrix:

```
x <- matrix(0, 10, 10)
```

Then fill in the columns:

```
for(i in 1:10) {
  x[, i] <- runif(1,0,10)
}
```

If you really want a vector at the end:

```
x <- as.numeric(x)
```

or you can accomplish this by removing the dimensions attribute:

```
dim(x) <- NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just create an additional 'for loop'. Use the first `for (i in 1:2)` to tell how many additional vectors of 10 values you need.

```
x <- x2 <- NULL
for (i in 1:2){
for(i in 1:10)
{
x[i] <- runif(1,0,10)
}
x2 <- c(x2, x)
}
```