# How do I append to a vector using a `while` loop?

Tags: r, vector, while-loop

I want to make a vector using a loop.

Here's my R code:

```
vec_teamCodes <- c()
x <- 0
while (x < 10) {
  append(vec_teamCodes,"Hello")
  x <- x+1
}
```

But when I run it, `vec_teamCodes()` remains `NULL`.

Why? How do I fix my code?

Comment: `append` does not assign value to variables in arguments, it creates a new variable.

Comment: I think you're either looking for `rep('Hello', 10)` or `paste(rep('Hello', 10), collapse = '')`

Comment: In general you will want to avoid extending vectors in this fashion. Though it works alright in this specific context, it is highly inefficient and will bite you in larger problems. Consider reading [@JoshuaUlrich's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22235924/3358272) to a question on appending to a vector.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
vec_teamCodes <- c()
x <- 0
while (x < 10) {
  vec_teamCodes <- c(vec_teamCodes,"Hello")
  # OR
  # vec_teamCodes <- append(vec_teamCodes,"Hello")
  x <- x+1
}


[1] "Hello" "Hello" "Hello" "Hello" "Hello" "Hello" "Hello" "Hello" "Hello" "Hello"
```

Comment: What are you starting with for `vec_teamCodes`?

Comment: @alistaire updated, was clear after seeing OP's question, though.

Comment: @Bulat Can you tell me why you edited my answer for for putting `=`?

Comment: or `vec_teamCodes <- numeric(0)`; OP should note for the long run that this idiom is inefficient in R.

Comment: @ZheyuanLi: yes, wasn't reading carefully (not much practical difference, but yours is more sensible)

Comment: I guess - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1741820/assignment-operators-in-r-and

Comment: @Bulat: this stylistic difference (`=` vs `<-`) has provoked minor religious wars in R mailing lists before now, so probably best not to modify others' code that way ...

Comment: Ok, I don't mind really ) that would be consistent with the question though, so it is not about the war on style.

Comment: @Bulat Well said -> Ben Bolker.