# Making a looping statement that populates a vector?

Tags: r

I've tried a couple ways of doing this problem but am having trouble with how to write it. I think I did the first three steps correctly, but now I have to fill the vector `z` with numbers from `y` that are divisible by four, not divisible by three, and have an odd number of digits. I know that I'm using the `print` function in the wrong way, I'm just at a loss on what else to use ... 
This is different from that other question because I'm not using a while loop.

```
#Step 1: Generate 1,000,000 random, uniformly distributed numbers between 0 
#and 1,000,000,000, and name as a vector x. With a seed of 1.
set.seed(1)
x=runif(1000000, min=0, max=1000000000)

#Step 2: Generate a rounded version of x with the name y
y=round(x,digits=0)

#Step 3: Empty vector named z
z=vector("numeric",length=0)

#Step 4: Create for loop that populates z vector with the numbers from y that are divisible by
#4, not divisible by 3, with an odd number of digits. 
for(i in y) {
  if(i%%4==0 && i%%3!=0 && nchar(i,type="chars",allowNA=FALSE,keepNA=NA)%%2!=0){
    print(z,i)
  }
}
```

Comment: to print a concatenated string, use the `paste` function. E.g., `print(paste0(z, i))`

Comment: and for this type of task, you don't (and shouldn't) need to use a loop (a direct subset of the data should work, something like `y[y%%4 == 0 & y%%3 != 0 & nchar(y) %% 2 != 0]` - untested!)

Comment: PS you don't need to specify all the optional arguments: `nchar(i)` should work fine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I append to a vector using a \`while\` loop?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37911963/how-do-i-append-to-a-vector-using-a-while-loop)

Comment: @SymbolixAU, it actually worked great! I didn't know you could make a direct subset like that. Sadly I have to make a looping function for my homework, and so I can't use this lovely solution T_T. It's good to know for the future that this works better though!

Comment: And @Ben Bolker, thanks for the tips! They really helped make my code neater.

Comment: You're welcome. I find it odd that in 'introduction to R' courses you're taught about `for` loops, yet they are often discouraged as subsetting is often far more efficient and the *r-way* of doing things

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NOTE: As per @BenBolker's comment, a loop is an inefficient way to solve your problem here. Generally, in R, try to avoid loops where possible to maximise the efficiency of your code. @SymbolixAU has provided an example of doing so here in the comments. Having said that, in aid of helping you learn the ins-and-outs of loops and vectors, here's a solution which only requires a change to one line of your code:

You've got the vector created before the loop, that's a good start. Now, inside your loop, you need to populate that vector. To do so, you've currently got `print(z,i)`, which won't really do too much. What you need to to change the vector itself:

```
z <- c( z, i )
```

Should work for you (just replace that `print` line in your loop).

What's happening here is that we're taking the existing `z` vector, binding `i` to the end of it, and making that new vector `z` again. So every time a value is added, the vector gets a little longer, such that you'll end up with a complete vector.

Comment: this works, but it should be noted that "growing" vectors in R is very inefficient; see @SymbolixAU's comment above for a better way

Comment: @BenBolker, I agree, but I get the impression the OP is learning about loops, vectors, etc. So I think the lesson of how to make the code work as it is is helpful. SymbolixAU's answer is certainly more efficient here though.

Comment: yes, I agree. Just *might* be worth mentioning for future reference, or for others who stop by to see the answer.

Comment: @BenBolker: Good point. I've added a note to my answer. Hopefully that gets both points across (learning a skill, and learning that the skill you just learned is not the best way to do things)... :)

Comment: Yep, @rosscova, this is for an intro to R class and we're learning how to write looping functions. Actually I tried to do this but I keep on getting plus signs next to the code in the console. Should I add something else to the code...? Thanks so much!!

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but it sounds like you might be missing a parentheses or something. If you enter a line of code that's incomplete, R will present you with a new line, to be used to complete your code. eg: `z<-c(z,2` presents a `+` prompt, which is R's way of saying "aaaaand theeeeeeennn..." since it can't complete that code until you close the parentheses.

Comment: I think it was something with the parentheses, since I put it all on one line and it worked. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

where you have `print` put this instead:

```
z <- append(z, i)
```