# How to find common variables in a list of datasets & reshape them in R?

Tags: r, loops, variables, dataset, reshape

```
    setwd("C:\\Users\\DATA")
    temp = list.files(pattern="*.dta")
    for (i in 1:length(temp)) assign(temp[i], read.dta13(temp[i], nonint.factors = TRUE))
    grep(pattern="_m", temp, value=TRUE)
```

Here I create a list of my datasets and read them into R, I then attempt to use `grep` in order to find all variable names with pattern _m, obviously this doesn't work because this simply returns all filenames with pattern _m. So essentially what I want, is my code to loop through the list of databases, find variables ending with _m, and return a list of databases that contain these variables.

Now I'm quite unsure how to do this, I'm quite new to coding and R.

Apart from needing to know in which databases these variables are, I also need to be able to make changes (reshape them) to these variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, `assign` will not work as you think, because it expects a string (or character, as they are called in R). It will use the first element as the variable (see [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/assign.html) for more info).

What you can do depends on the structure of your data. read.dta13 will load each file as a data.frame.

If you look for column names, you can do something like that:

```
myList <- character()
for (i in 1:length(temp)) {

    # save the content of your file in a data frame
    df <- read.dta13(temp[i], nonint.factors = TRUE))

    # identify the names of the columns matching your pattern
    varMatch <- grep(pattern="_m", colnames(df), value=TRUE)

    # check if at least one of the columns match the pattern
    if (length(varMatch)) {
        myList <- c(myList, temp[i]) # save the name if match
    }

}
```

If you look for the content of a column, you can have a look at the dplyr package, which is very useful when it comes to data frames manipulation.

A good introduction to dplyr is available in the package vignette [here](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html).

Note that in R, appending to a vector can become very slow (see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22235809/append-value-to-empty-vector-in-r) for more details).

Comment: Thank you for answering! But how do I actually view the list that we saved the names to? Right now it seems to be in my Global Environment tab below data under 'Values'.

Comment: You are right, the names are in the vector myList. You can access it as you wish, but typing myList at the prompt will display its content in the console.

Comment: Okay this works, now I got a list of datasets containing the variables that I need. Now, what if from that new list I want to extract all columns from every dataset that are named 'a' , 'b' or contain pattern "_m" and put them in a new dataset?

Comment: I thought maybe I could do this, after saving the content of the files in a dataframe, inside the loop by typing: m <- select(df, a, b, (grep("_m", colnames(df), value=TRUE))). But I guess that doesn't work...

Comment: you would do the same as before, but with a different regex using the OR operator: `grep( '^(a|b|_m)*$', colnames(df), value=TRUE)` should work. It looks for at least one occurence (symbol *) of either a,b or _m (OR statements in the parenthesis) between the beg (symbol ^) and the end (symbol $) of each column name.

Comment: sorry I had misunderstood what you tried to do. What you did does not work because you cannot directly pass a vector as column names. Try using `select_(df, .dots = c("a","b", grep("_m", colnames(df), value=TRUE)))`. See the dplyr "nse" vignette here: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/nse.html

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to figure out which files have variables with names ending in "_m":

```
# setup
setwd("C:\\Users\\DATA")
temp = list.files(pattern="*.dta")
# logical vector to be filled in
inFileVec <- logical(length(temp))

# loop through each file
for (i in 1:length(temp)) {
  # read file
  fileTemp <- read.dta13(temp[i], nonint.factors = TRUE)

  # fill in vector with TRUE if any variable ends in "_m"
  inFileVec[i] <- any(grepl("_m$", names(fileTemp)))
}
```

In the final line, `names` returns the variable names, `grepl` returns a logical vector for whether each variable name matches the pattern, and `any` returns a logical vector of length 1 indicating whether or not at least one TRUE was returned from `grepl`.

```
# print out these file names    
temp[inFileVec]
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! The last line 'temp[inFileVec]' just says 'character(0)' as output, what does that mean?

Comment: Try printing out the names of the columns in the loop: `cat(names(fileTemp))`.

Comment: hmm it gives a bunch of variable names but none of them match the "_m'' pattern strangely..

Comment: So none of the variable names, perhaps translated when read in by `read.dta13`, use that pattern. Are there ".m" patterns at the end? If so, use "\\.m$" in `grepl` instead.

Comment: I'm sure there are _m patterns, it just gives the same variables no matter what I give as a pattern. Also it seems like fileTemp is just one of the datasets, so maybe there is something going wrong while looping through each file?

Comment: Try manually reading in the first ten files of temp and see what the variable names are.