# using a longer query to extract shorter targets in a list with partial matches using r

Tags: r, regex, string

Extracting elements with a partial match is simple.

```
# List of longer names
long_names <- c("apple_pie", "banana_split", "cherry_pie", "lemon_meringue", "blueberry_muffin")

# Partial match pattern
partial_match <- "pie"

# Find the index of the first match
match_index <- grep(partial_match, long_names)

# Extract the corresponding shorter name
short_name <- long_names[match_index]

# Print the result
print(short_name)
```

output

```
[1] "apple_pie" "cherry_pie"
```

Is there a way to something a similar, but with a list of shorter names, using a longer query? The best I came up with is the following.

```
# List of shorter names
short_names <- c("apple", "banana", "cherry", "lemon", "blueberry")

# Longer name (query)
long_name <- "cherry_pie"

# Initialize an empty vector to store partial matches
partial_match <- c()

# Iterate over each short name
for (i in 1:length(short_names)) {
  # Check if the short name is a partial match in the long name
  if (grepl(short_names[i], long_name)) {
    # If it is, add it to the output vector
    partial_match <- c(partial_match, short_names[i])
  }
}

# Print the partial matches
print(partial_match)
```

output

```
[1] "cherry"
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Will your `long_name` always be length one? If so you can use `stringr::str_detect()` which will recycle the shorter vector to the length of the longer one. However, if the length will vary, you'll need some sort of iteration, either in a loop as you have done, or with `lapply()` like functions.

Comment: The length of long_name is expected to be more than one. For now, I am dealing with n = 178 for the query and n = 18658 for the list. I probably will have to do a few more of the same later. My method is manageable with what I have, but it is slow -- maybe a minute or so with my laptop.

Comment: Probably your code is slow because you're growing a vector. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22235809/append-value-to-empty-vector-in-r

Comment: This indeed could be a part of the problem, although not a serious one. What I am doing is going through 18658 list. With each of 18658, there is one match expected among 178. Technically, there is no reason to grow a vector, and the vector never grows to more than 1 in my case; I could not think of another approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With base R, you can use `regmatches`

```
> regmatches(long_name, gregexpr(paste0(short_names, collapse = "|"), long_name))
[[1]]
[1] "cherry"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. I can't imagine a better answer within the R environment. This is faster than my original method going through n=18658 (~30 sec vs >50 sec).

Answer (score 1):

Possible approaches:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# With one long_name
short_names <- c("apple", "banana", "cherry", "lemon", "blueberry")
long_name <- "cherry_pie"

short_names[which(str_detect(long_name, short_names))]
#> [1] "cherry"

# Multiple long_names
long_names <- c("cherry_pie", "apple_pie")

map(long_names, \(x) {
  short_names[which(str_detect(x, short_names))]
  })
#> [[1]]
#> [1] "cherry"
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] "apple"
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-17 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>